# how i can put two filter conditions where name='SHIPMENT.ORDERS.ORREFNUMS.REFNUM_VALUE' and value node contains ":" in the value

Tags: xpath

i want to filter where name=SHIPMENT.ORDERS.ORREFNUMS.REFNUM_VALUE and contains ":" in the value.

```
    <inputData name="SHIPMENT.ORDERS.ORREFNUMS.REFNUM_VALUE" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/ExternalRating">
        <values xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/ExternalRating">
            <value xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/ExternalRating">24-100</value>
            <value xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/ExternalRating">RC3.B726030-001-CO8MODF183896704</value>
            <value xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/ExternalRating">Y</value>
            <value xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/ExternalRating">2022-06-23 23:59:59</value>
        </values>
    </inputData>
```

Comment: What output do you want to get? Can you give an example? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: i am expecting this in the out put "2022-06-23 23:59:59"

Comment: my request contains multiple <inputdata> elements and my requirement is to extract the datetime parameters in the values using xpath where name='SHIPMENT.ORDERS.ORREFNUMS.REFNUM_VALUE'.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the actual structure of `<values>` you could, as specified in your question, use:

```
//inputData[@name="SHIPMENT.ORDERS.ORREFNUMS.REFNUM_VALUE"]//value[contains(.,":")]/text()
```

If the datetime element is always the 4th `<value>` you can try:

```
//inputData[@name="SHIPMENT.ORDERS.ORREFNUMS.REFNUM_VALUE"]//value[4]/text()
```

or, if it's always the last `<value>`:

```
 //inputData[@name="SHIPMENT.ORDERS.ORREFNUMS.REFNUM_VALUE"]//value[last()]/text()
```

Comment: They'll need to specify a namespace as well, of course. In some environments (e.g. in XSLT 2 and later) you can declare an XPath default namespace, but in many environments you need to bind a namespace prefix e.g. "rating" to the namespace URI "http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/ExternalRating", and then use that prefix in the XPath expression, e.g. `//rating:inputData[@name="SHIPMENT.ORDERS.ORREFNUMS.REFNUM_VALUE"]//rating:value[contains(.,":")]/text()`